# Video play error in Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

i am working on an actionscript3 project. when i am loading the video file in a class without the e:Event parameter;

```
private function setupVideo_2():void
                {
                    vid = new Video(640,480);
                    addChild(vid);

                    nc= new NetConnection();
                    nc.connect(null);

                    ns= new NetStream(nc);
                    vid.attachNetStream(ns);

                    var listener:Object = new Object();
                    listener.onMetaData= function (evt:Object):void{};
                    ns.client = listener;

                    ns.play("introduction to 3G and 4G.flv");

                }
```

it plays fine. 
The moment i put it in the condition stating play only when the marker pattern is sited; it loadz but there is a visible lag followed by stopping of the video and repeating of the first line around 3 times and then the air application stops working and eventually crashes.
here is the code for it.

```
private function loop (e:Event):void
   {
       bmd.draw(vid);

    try
    {
        if (detector.detectMarkerLite(raster, 80)&& detector.getConfidence() > 0.5)
            {
                    vid = new Video(640,480);
                    addChild(vid);

                    nc= new NetConnection();
                    nc.connect(null);

                    ns= new NetStream(nc);
                    vid.attachNetStream(ns);

                    var listener:Object = new Object();
                    listener.onMetaData= function (evt:Object):void{};
                    ns.client = listener;
                    ns.play("4 Clever Ethernet Cable Hacks.flv");


                }

            }

            catch(e:Error){}

        }
```

Please tell me why is the video lagging when played inside the if condition.

Comment: loop? what are you looping?

Comment: loop is just a function name for easy readability for me. The main purpose of the function is to play the video only when the marker.pat file is detected. It is playing multiple instance of this .flv file when loaded in the' if ' condition.